# Какие данные содержатся в qr коде от сбербанка?

Tags: qrcode, qr

Если сканировать код с картинки то выведет ссылку вида:

```
https://sberbank.ru/qr/uuid=1000305877
```

А если эту же ссылку сгенерировать в гугл, то она визуально отличается

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=https://sberbank.ru/qr/uuid=1000305877&chs=354x354&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0
```

Какие данные ещё зашифрованы в этом коде от сбера?
Писал и такой шаблон со всеми реквизитами, но тоже отличаются qr коды.

```
ST00011|Name=магаз|PersonalAcc=4070281017|BankName=ОАО"БАНК"|BIC=044525225|CorrespAcc=301000225
```

Может генератор гугла не правильно настроен или не полная информация в коде.

[image: qr code]

Comment: *А если эту же ссылку сгенерировать в гугл, то она визуально отличается* Скажи ещё спасибо, что на этом сгенерированном QR нету рекламного объявления. *Какие данные ещё зашифрованы в этом коде от сбера?* Каком "этом"? в изначальном - никакие. А что туда тебе напихали до кучи от гугла - разбирайся самостоятельно, буде оно тебе надо...

Comment: Знаете какие хорошие варианты на php или script или сервис какой?

Comment: Для чего? для генерации куара? да любой онлайн... делаешь куар, сканируешь, проверяешь, что ссылка не изменена... если туда хоть пробел лишний сунули - чёрная метка, и тестишь следующий генератор.

Comment: У QR-кода есть 4 уровня коррекции ошибок, 8 фильтров и несколько кодировок. Так что картинки у разных генераторов могут не совпадать, это нормально.